# Loading an out of tree module as builtin in Yocto

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

I have added an out of tree module in my yocto layer.. This builds the driver as module(.ko)

I want this to be builtin in the kernel image.. What all changes should I make for this to be achieved.

Comment: In Yocto you may add a special kernel configuration excerpts and use them when building your image. There you need to specify *CONFIG_MY_COOL_DRIVER=y*.

Comment: You need to integrate it with the Linux kernel source tree. You cannot build it in outside of it.

Comment: How to integrate it with the Linux source code. Do I need to create a patch